# How to get parent id in unlimited nested array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

It is as the title, but I am facing a problem!

I want to create `getParentId(array, id)` function.

This function get parent id by child id.

```
const array = [{
  id: 1,
  title: 'hello',
  children: [{
    id: 3,
    title: 'hello',
    children: [{
      id: 4,
      title:'hello',
      children: [
        { id: 5, title: 'hello'},
        { id: 6, title: 'hello'}
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 7,
      title: 'hello'
    }]
  }]
},
{
  id: 2,
  title: 'hello',
  children: [
    { id: 8, title: 'hello'}
  ]
}]
```

- This array may nest indefinitely

Expected Result:

```
getParentId(array, 3) -> 1

getParentId(array, 5) -> 4

getParentId(array, 6) -> 4

getParentId(array, 8) -> 2

getParentId(array, 2) -> null
```

I would be grateful if you would send me information.

Comment: Welcome. Please share your attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a recursive approach by iterating the actual array and their children and stop if the `id` is found.

```js
function getParentId(array, id, parentId = null) {
    return array.some(o => {
        if (o.id === id) return true;
        const temp = getParentId(o.children || [], id, o.id);
        if (temp !== null) {
            parentId = temp;
            return true;
        }
    })
        ? parentId
        : null;
}

const array = [{ id: 1, title: 'hello', children: [{ id: 3, title: 'hello', children: [{ id: 4, title:'hello', children: [{ id: 5, title: 'hello' }, { id: 6, title: 'hello' }] }, { id: 7, title: 'hello' }] }] }, { id: 2, title: 'hello', children: [{ id: 8, title: 'hello' }] }];

console.log(getParentId(array, 3)); // 1
console.log(getParentId(array, 5)); // 4
console.log(getParentId(array, 6)); // 4
console.log(getParentId(array, 8)); // 2
console.log(getParentId(array, 2)); // null
console.log(getParentId(array, 7)); // 3
console.log(getParentId(array, 4)); // 3
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Can you explain why you check if `parentId ... !== null` at line 4?

Comment: that is part of the exit condition for `some`, to prevent having `parentId` with a non valid value.

Comment: Should also work without `!== null` since `null` is falsy anyway. But it can be argued that it is clearer this way.

Comment: the above code is not working for 7 and 4

Comment: @K.S, you are right. it was missing another variable and the need to overwrite `parentId` only if the returned value is not `null`. please see edit.

Comment: @NinaScholz  actually I came across this post  regarding this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75470984/get-all-its-parent-nodes-path-for-each-child-nodes
Can you help here?

Answer (score 1):

Nina Scholz's answer is great, but here's a slightly less functional approach (not using `Array.some`), if you like it better:

```js
const array = [{id: 1, title: 'hello', children: [{id: 3, title: 'hello', children: [{id: 4, title:'hello', children: [{ id: 5, title: 'hello'}, { id: 6, title: 'hello'}]}, {id: 7, title: 'hello'}]}]}, {id: 2, title: 'hello', children: [{ id: 8, title: 'hello'}]}];

function getParentId(array, id, parentId = null) {
  // For every entry in the array
  for (const entry of array) {
    // If the ID matches, return the current parent ID
    if (entry.id === id) {
      return parentId;
    }
    // Otherwise, call the same function on its children, passing itself as the parent.
    // If there was a match, return it.
    if (entry.children && (deeperParentId = getParentId(entry.children, id, entry.id))) {
      return deeperParentId;
    }
  }
  // No match was found
  return null;
}

console.log(getParentId(array, 3));
console.log(getParentId(array, 5));
console.log(getParentId(array, 6));
console.log(getParentId(array, 8));
console.log(getParentId(array, 2));
```

Note that I overcommented it, which is not such a good idea when writing actual code; this is just for the answer.

Also, as I mentioned in the comments, please share your attempts next time.

Comment: This is exactly my deleted answer but with a couple of mistakes fixed. Now I see what I did wrong...