# Get all its parent nodes path for each child nodes

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, nested

Hi I have below code running, but I would like to add one more property called path which should consist all its  parent node path

Expected output I need something as I have shown for cardTtile, so I need same for each node.

```
[
  {
    "id": "cardShop",
    "key": "cardShop",
    "title": "cardShop",
    "selectable": false,
     "path":cardShop"
    "children": [
      {
        "id": "cardData",
        "key": "cardData",
        "title": "cardData",
        "parentId": "cardShop",
        "path":cardShop.cardData"
        "selectable": false,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "cardTitle",
            "key": "cardTitle",
            "title": "cardTitle",
            "parentId": "cardData",
             "path":cardShop.cardData.cardTitle"
            "isLeaf": true
          },
          {
            "id": "cardType",
            "key": "cardType",
            "title": "cardType",
            "parentId": "cardData",
            "isLeaf": true
          },
          {
            "id": "dtmProductName",
            "key": "dtmProductName",
            "title": "dtmProductName",
            "parentId": "cardData",
            "isLeaf": true
          },
          {
            "id": "viewAllCards",
            "key": "viewAllCards",
            "title": "viewAllCards",
            "parentId": "cardData",
            "selectable": false,
            "children": [
              {
                "id": "url",
                "key": "url",
                "title": "url",
                "parentId": "viewAllCards",
                "isLeaf": true
              },
              {
                "id": "text",
                "key": "text",
                "title": "text",
                "parentId": "viewAllCards",
                "isLeaf": true
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "eligibilityChecker",
        "key": "eligibilityChecker",
        "title": "eligibilityChecker",
        "parentId": "cardShop",
        "selectable": false,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": "header",
            "key": "header",
            "title": "header",
            "parentId": "eligibilityChecker",
            "isLeaf": true
          },
          {
            "id": "subHeader",
            "key": "subHeader",
            "title": "subHeader",
            "parentId": "eligibilityChecker",
            "isLeaf": true
          },
          {
            "id": "bulletPoints",
            "key": "bulletPoints",
            "title": "bulletPoints",
            "parentId": "eligibilityChecker",
            "isLeaf": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have below running code example here. I tried to persist parentKey recursively but its not giving me expected output.

```js
const transform = data => {
 const loop  = (data, parent) => Object.entries(data).map(([key, value]) => {
    let additional = parent? {
      parentId: parent
    }:{}
    
    if(typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)){
      additional = {
       ...additional,
       selectable: false,
       children: loop(value, key)
       
      }
    }else{
      additional.isLeaf = true
    }
    
    return {
      id: key,
      key,
      title: key,
      ...additional
    }
 })
 
 return loop(data)
}


let jsonObj = {
  "data": {
    "cardShop": {
      "cardData": {
        "cardTitle": "The Platinum Card<sup>®</sup>",
        "cardType": "credit-cards",
        "dtmProductName": "PlatinumCard",
        "viewAllCards": {
          "url": "credit-cards/all-cards",
          "text": "All Cards"
        }
      },
      "eligibilityChecker": {
        "header": "Check your eligibility",
        "subHeader": "The Platinum Card®",
        "bulletPoints": [
          "Only takes a couple of minutes to complete",
          "Will not impact your credit rating",
          "Allows you to apply with confidence"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

console.log(transform(jsonObj.data))
```

```html
]
```

You suggestion would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could take another variable for `path` and add the actual `key` to it.

```js
const transform = data => {
    const loop = (data, parentId, previousPath = '') => Object
        .entries(data)
        .map(([key, value]) => {
            const
                additional = parentId ? { parentId } : {},
                path = previousPath  + (previousPath && '.') + key;

            Object.assign(
                additional,
                value && typeof value === 'object' && !Array.isArray(value)
                    ? { selectable: false, children: loop(value, key, path) }
                    : { isLeaf: true }
            );

            return { id: key, key, title: key, path, ...additional };
        });

    return loop(data);
}

const data = { cardShop: { cardData: { cardTitle: "The Platinum Card<sup>®</sup>", cardType: "credit-cards", dtmProductName: "PlatinumCard", viewAllCards: { url: "credit-cards/all-cards", text: "All Cards" } }, eligibilityChecker: { header: "Check your eligibility", subHeader: "The Platinum Card®", bulletPoints: ["Only takes a couple of minutes to complete", "Will not impact your credit rating", "Allows you to apply with confidence"] } } };

console.log(transform(data));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```